# "Even if" vs "although"

Tags: canadian-english

Are thoes two words used in different situation?

Is there any examples that can explain the difference between two words?

Answer (score 1):

Although means "despite the fact that", even if means " whether or not".

Although and even if, though close in meaning, are not equivalent.

Although describes a factual position such as " Although he was ill, he worked hard". "Although it's raining, I'll go out for a walk".

On the other hand, even if indicates a rather  hypothetical condition. It tells us that whether a situation or condition is true or not, something happens such as "Even if it's raining, he goes out for a walk".

In other words, both "although" and "even if" are used to introduce a subordinate clause which contains a statement that contrasts with the statement in the main clause, but "even if" is indicative of a stronger contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples of your situation and need to understand the difference of these words are:

**Even if I get my chores done, I am not going to the ball**

These words/phrases are not interchangeable.

**Although I get my chores done, I am not going to the ball**

The second one doesn't make sense. They may be Synonyms but do not have the same meaning. They both provide different character/feeling behind the word.

**From** [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/although?&o=100074&s=t)

although

[awl-th oh]

**conjunction**

1.
in spite of the fact that; even though; though.

**Example sentence:**

**Although** they were rich, they lived simply and were at peace with all the world.

Even if, Even when, or Even as are all bringing out the same meaning just in different tenses.

**From** [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/even?s=t)

**Even**

[ee-vuh n]

**adverb**

even (just; used to emphasize occurrence, coincidence, or simultaneousness of occurrences):

**Example sentence:**

**Even as** he lay dying, they argued over his estate.